# Multiple Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I had a working application, and then I learned to use cocoapods and I installed CWPopup. I had not tried to run the app since I started using the .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj so I think that may be the problem, but I'm not sure.

I had zero errors and then I tried to run it and now I have 14 errors, all saying Apple Mach-O Linker Error. Underneath each one I see different things mentioning twitter and facebook seesions and requests and such. I don't even use twitter or facebook in my app, this is a very basic app.

Comment: That's not enough information.

Comment: Is this by any chance on XCode 6 beta ? Does it throw the error when building for simulator or device or both?

Comment: Show a sample error please.

Answer (score 0):

This error says that you lost some required frameworks or libraries in your project. Check in your Targets->Build Phases-> Link Binary With Labraries is all required frameworks and libraries added.